# Setting Raspberry PI 3 as wireless access point without internet access

Tags: networking, wifi, android

I'm developing a project where I need to connect an Android device to a Raspberry Pi 3 to perform HTTP connections without using internet access. I just want to have a local domain.

EDIT:

I'm trying to connect an Android device to the Raspberry PI using the wlan0 as Access Point. The Android device will work as a http client and the Raspberry Pi as a http server so I need a network to perform this in a local domain.

I followed a lot of guides but all of them use the Raspberry PI as a WiFi repeater. I try to connect my android device to my ad hoc network but It doesn't work.

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: How can I do it? I want to do an ad-hoc but It seems like it's imposible without internet access.

Comment: Please add the question to the initial posting. Please also explain _what_ exact issues your are facing when try to do that. "seems like it's imposible" does not explain what problems you are actually facing. Do you get any error messages? What have you tried already and how did it fail?

Answer (score 1):

You obviously do not need internet access to do this -- why would you?

If you want to work with ad hoc mode, just configure the wireless interface for ad hoc mode (read the man pages for `iw` and `iwconfig`), use an RFC1918 subnet that you are not otherwise using (e.g., 192.168.100.0/24), and set up `dhcpd` to give an address to your android device (or configure your android device with a static IP address).

Or you can use hostapd and set up the pi as an access point; you'll still need to decide on what address space to use, and you'll still need to set up dhcpd.

Of course, none of this is Pi-specific.