# raspberry pi as access point with captive portal

Tags: pi-3, access-point, captive-portal

I recently got a raspberry pi. I have it set up as an access point in a standalone network (not connected to the internet). I can also serve a static website on this network. I've been trying to set up a captive portal so that when a user joins the network it automatically takes them to this website.

Looking at these tutorials:

[This is how I set up the access point](http://raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point.md)

[For captive portal using nodogsplash](http://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-captive-portal/)

So the access point is working but honestly, I have no clue about how the captive portal works with this. I'm wondering whether the pi has to be connected to the internet for the captive portal to work? If anyone knows anything useful, I will forever be in your debt.

Comment: I hope this helps you take a look: https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-captive-portal/

Comment: If you don't need Internet access and just want to serve an HTML page in the captive portal, I've published [this MIT-licensed repo](https://github.com/Splines/raspi-captive-portal) with a setup script for access point, captive portal and web server.

Comment: I found a lot of information on the Internet was out of date on how to set up a simple captive portal on the Raspi 4 (currently debian 11, bullseye). [Here](https://github.com/Splines/raspi-captive-portal) is a repo I've spun up to simplify the installation.

Answer (score 5):

Captive portals work because devices make a DNS request to specific URLS, depending on which operating system, and they expect a success response. If they get a redirect instead, then they will show that new site as a captive portal.

A list of some of the URL's can be found here: [How Automatic Detection of Captive Portal works](https://success.tanaza.com/s/article/How-Automatic-Detection-of-Captive-Portal-works).

If you followed that tutorial, then you can change your DNS server to redirect any request to a domain that isn't yours to the Raspberry Pi. The `/etc/dnsmasq.conf` file controls the DNS server. Add the following line to redirect all requests (change the IP address if you chose not to use `192.168.4.1`)

`address=/#/192.168.1.1`

You will then need to set up your webserver to redirect those requests. I suggest choosing a URL, like `http://mysite/`, and telling your webserver (such as nginx) to show your site for that domain, and send a `redirect` for all other domains.

For setting up redirects, see the following pages

- Nginx [How To Create Temporary and Permanent Redirects with Nginx](https://linuxhostsupport.com/blog/how-to-create-temporary-and-permanent-redirects-with-nginx/)
- Apache [How To Create Temporary and Permanent Redirects with Apache and Nginx](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-temporary-and-permanent-redirects-with-apache-and-nginx)

Comment: Certainly efficient. But it also redirects all requests from the local system as well, not just requests from the Access Point. Effectively, you kill dns when logged in interactively. :-(

Answer (score 5):

Follow the instruction:

**1. Config the RPi as a Wifi Access point or a Wifi Hotspot**

```
sudo apt-get -y install hostapd dnsmasq 

nano /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
```

Add the config below to the hostapd.conf file:

```
interface=wlan0
driver=nl80211
ssid=MyPiAP
hw_mode=g
channel=6
ieee80211n=1
wmm_enabled=1
ht_capab=[HT40][SHORT-GI-20][DSSS_CCK-40]
macaddr_acl=0
auth_algs=1
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
wpa=2
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_passphrase=raspberry
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
```

Edit hostapd:

```
nano /etc/default/hostapd
```

Change this part to:

```
DAEMON_CONF="/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf"
```

Then:

```
sudo mv /etc/dnsmasq.conf /etc/dnsmasq.conf.bak
sudo nano /etc/dnsmasq.conf
```

Add these lines to dnsmasq.conf :

```
interface=wlan0 
listen-address=192.168.5.1
bind-interfaces 
server=8.8.8.8
domain-needed
bogus-priv
dhcp-range=192.168.5.100,192.168.5.200,24h
```

Start the `hostapd` service:

```
sudo service hostapd start
```

If you face to a problem in this step, check [this link](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/108683/44221) out.

Enable IP Forwarding:

```
nano /etc/sysctl.conf
```

Uncomment:

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

Add these commands for the firewall and packet forwarding:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE  
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o wlan0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan0 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT  

sh -c "iptables-save > /etc/iptables.ipv4.nat"  



sudo nano /etc/rc.local
```

add these lines before **Exit 0**:

```
iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.ipv4.nat  
ifconfig wlan0 192.168.5.1
```

Finally, `reboot` the device and check it out by a Wifi client. You must connect to the internet.
Note that, you need to connect to internet by **eth0** interface.

**2. Now, it's the time to using nodogsplash, which is the captive portal software:**

```
sudo apt install git libmicrohttpd-dev

git clone https://github.com/nodogsplash/nodogsplash.git

cd nodogsplash
make
sudo make install

sudo nano /etc/nodogsplash/nodogsplash.conf
```

Change the configuration to:

```
GatewayInterface wlan0
GatewayAddress 192.168.5.1
MaxClients 250
AuthIdleTimeout 480
```

Add `nodogsplash` command to rc.local:

```
sudo nano /etc/rc.local
```

add this line before **Exit 0**:

```
iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.ipv4.nat
```

Now, you can connect to the **MyPiAP** SSID and the splash page will appear. Tap the Continue button for connecting to the internet.
Done.

Answer (score 1):

In case of you need a customizable captive portal you can install all using this project Kupiki https://github.com/pihomeserver/Kupiki-Hotspot-Script

Once installed you can replace the captive portal by what ever you want using the Nginx configuration.

Internet is not mandatory. It's usefull if you want the page to be closed automatically once you are authenticated as it tries to reach a specific page to confirm that Internet is up