# Using a Raspberry Pi to connect to a Public Hotspot

Tags: wifi, access-point

Is there a way to use a Raspberry Pi to take a (public) WiFi Signal and create a hotspot such that devices can connect wirelessly to the internet via the Pi?

Moreover, can this be done if a network has no password set but requires a user to login with credentials?

The use of this would be to create an access point for multiple devices if a login to a network would have to be acquired separately.

Comment: Check it out. https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/106018/44221

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting up an [Access point as WiFi router/repeater](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/89804/79866) is not a problem.

The problem is the user to login with credentials. I suppose this is done with the internet browser on a login page. You can script this login but there is no standard login procedure. Every site has its own procedure so you have to script every login separately. And it is not a simple task to script it. You have to analyze the html GETs and PUTs and send the expected pages with login data. Or you use a "browser emulator" that can handle dialogs automatically in a human way.

Comment: As my experience using the Pi for Networking is limited to PiHole and PiVPN, I still have a few qustions: 

If I do not plan on using the Pi's ethernet port, neither for the clients, nor for the connection to the host, I will not need to set up a bridge, right?

Could I simply log the Pi onto the WiFi using a Monitor and just use wlan0 to connect to the Hotspot (be it with or without credentials) and pass it to wlan1 for the other devices?
If so, which settings should be entered in Step 2 of setting up the repeater, under "ssid=, country_code= and wpa_passphrase="?

Comment: @RomanStadler This are quite different questions from what you have asked. Yes, it is possible to do but comments are not a good place for answering. You may consider to make a new question.