# How to Create a Raspberry PI Real time camera server?

Tags: wifi, camera

I have created a Real-time camera server using the Raspberry PI and I can access the live feed through the static IP address of Raspberry Pi over the LAN. But I want to create something like:

1. When the Raspberry PI is turned on, it will have a Wi-Fi name.
2. When I open my mobile phone Wi-Fi setting and search for Wi-Fi available there will be displayed the Raspberry PI name and after clicking on the Raspberry PI name I have to enter the password and then after connecting to Raspberry PI, I will be able to view live feed through Mobile app or in a browser(Which will be I think basically accessed through the IP address of Raspberry PI after connecting to it).

I am not able to find a way to achieve the first and second steps? Any guide or tutorial link Please share.

I am also searching but couldn't find it as I don't know its proper term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have configured my raspberry pi to something like you said.

> I will be able to view live feed through Mobile app or in a browser

The `motion` is here for you. It has a web interface that you can see the camera's stream in real-time.

[How to Make Raspberry Pi Webcam Server and Stream Live Video || Motion + Webcam + Raspberry Pi](https://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-Make-Raspberry-Pi-Webcam-Server-and-Stream-/)

---

> 1. When the Raspberry PI is turned on, it will have a Wi-Fi name.

Make a wifi hotspot for the raspberry pi. You can do it simply by following the procedure on this link:

[Setting up a Raspberry Pi as a Wireless Access Point](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point.md)

After that, the raspberry pi has a "Wi-Fi name" as you mentioned, and your clients (PC, Smartphone, iOS, Android, etc)

---

In conclusion, after all of this two sections you can connect to raspberry pi's SSID (Wifi name) and open a web page to see the real-time streams.

[image]

---

I have an idea to make your project better. You can configure the raspberry pi to show the camera web page to clients exactly after they connect to the raspberry pi's hotspot. To do that, follow [this answer's procedures](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/106018/44221).

Comment: I have followed that instructable guide only. I will try this right away and that splash page Idea is very awesome but I am going to create a Mobile android application through which I will connect to the raspberry pi's hotspot and directly will start receiving the feed. Which I don't know how to do? can you suggest regarding this?

Comment: @Lucifer I suggest starting the project and do these simple steps and after that, you can start mobile side project. You can make an app to always doing something. For example, the app always is listening to `http://raspberrypi:8080` and shows the output to a web-view box. If you have connected to the raspberry pi, everything is going well and if you disconnected, it shows a message which can be "something went wrong, make sure the connection of the raspberry pi wifi".

Comment: Hey, I followed the procedure stated in this: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/88438/raspberry-pi-as-access-point-with-captive-portal/106018#106018

to create Raspberry Pi as an access point but raspberry pi isn't acting as a WAP

Comment: @Lucifer Did you set an IP address to the `wlan0`? Which part do you stock?

Comment: I followed the above answer whose Link I have given till the creating of the splash page. I didn't do any extra things. Also, I connected the ethernet cable to the PI and turned Wi-Fi was on. Then I rebooted the system and I didn't log in to PI user just to test. Still no WAP.

Comment: When I search for Wi-Fi in Mobile I should see the Raspberry PIs name but I am not seeing anything.

Comment: Created there was some missing things in the official documentation and also in that answer.

Comment: If I want to show my live feed on the splash screen then I should replace the gateway address to the IP address with the port of my streaming IP right.

Comment: @Lucifer Which step do you stock in? || Yes you have to set dhcp server which the gateway is the raspberry pi (wlan0).

Comment: I replaced the gateway address with the Raspberry Pi's address(Which is also the default for streaming) that is: Streaming IP : 192.168.1.1:8081, And GatewayAddress replaced in nodogsplash.conf : 192.168.1.1. Still I am not getting the splash page. I have not changed anything beside what was said in that answer.

Comment: @Lucifer Ok. The splash page will be shown in `http://192.168.1.1:2050` therefore open up this page to make sure is it working. NOTE THAT there is some bugs/policy with different smartphones so you should test the captive portal with different devices to make sure there is a problem. Please do it step by step. At first, make sure the hotspot is OK, I mean if you connect a smartphone, will that phone access to the internet. Then, if it's done without any problem, configure device as a captive portal system. Bear it in mind that if the internet connection is disabled, the splash page not works.

Comment: Okay, checked and splash page comes for one time only and even if I forget the network and try to rejoin. But I don't need it I think because as I read for showing the camera feed I have to edit the splash.html page and then it will be shown. But what I wanted was as soon as I connect (not need a splash) just directly got to the streaming IP address then it is good.

Comment: @Lucifer Ok, great job. To be honest I have had this problem with one of my Chinese smartphone and It shows the splash page once a day. I read a lot and deduced it's their policies.