# hostapd problems while setting up Pi 4 as Access Point

Tags: wireless, pi-4, access-point, hostapd

First of all i want  to say that i'm new to all of this, so please dont hate me if the answer to my problem seemed obvious to you.

I just tried to follow [this tutorial](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point.md) to set up my Pi 4 as an Access Point.

I have the newest version of Raspbian Buster Lite installed.

I follows all the steps, but i got stuck after "Configuring the access point host software (hostapd)"

When i try to start hostapd i get the following massage:

```
Job for hostapd.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status hostapd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

when i then use the systemctl status hostapd.service command i get this:

```
● hostapd.service - Advanced IEEE 802.11 AP and IEEE 802.1X/WPA/WPA2/EAP Authenticator
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/hostapd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2020-02-23 17:56:22 CET; 333ms ago
  Process: 2101 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/hostapd -B -P /run/hostapd.pid -B $DAEMON_OPTS ${DAEMON_CONF} (code=exited, status=1
```

when i use journalctl -xe i get the following:

```
Feb 23 17:57:36 raspberrypi hostapd[2159]: wlan0: AP-DISABLED
Feb 23 17:57:36 raspberrypi hostapd[2159]: wlan0: Unable to setup interface.
Feb 23 17:57:36 raspberrypi hostapd[2159]: wlan0: interface state DISABLED->DISABLED
Feb 23 17:57:36 raspberrypi hostapd[2159]: wlan0: AP-DISABLED
Feb 23 17:57:36 raspberrypi hostapd[2159]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-TERMINATING
Feb 23 17:57:36 raspberrypi hostapd[2159]: hostapd_free_hapd_data: Interface wlan0 wasn't started
Feb 23 17:57:36 raspberrypi hostapd[2159]: nl80211: deinit ifname=wlan0 disabled_11b_rates=0
Feb 23 17:57:36 raspberrypi systemd[1]: hostapd.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
-- Subject: Unit process exited
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
--
-- An ExecStart= process belonging to unit hostapd.service has exited.
--
-- The process' exit code is 'exited' and its exit status is 1.
Feb 23 17:57:36 raspberrypi systemd[1]: hostapd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
-- Subject: Unit failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
--
-- The unit hostapd.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
Feb 23 17:57:36 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Failed to start Advanced IEEE 802.11 AP and IEEE 802.1X/WPA/WPA2/EAP Authenticator.
-- Subject: A start job for unit hostapd.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
--
-- A start job for unit hostapd.service has finished with a failure.
--
-- The job identifier is 32180 and the job result is failed.
```

Now, like i said, im a total noob. I'm trying to learn all of this, but i din't find anything about this problem.

Ps: I have OMV installed, could that somehow be the problem or be connected to the problem?
If yes, how do i create an AP while still using OMV?

EDIT:
    cat /lib/systemd/system/hostapd.service
outputs the following:

```
[Unit]
Description=Advanced IEEE 802.11 AP and IEEE 802.1X/WPA/WPA2/EAP Authenticator
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
PIDFile=/run/hostapd.pid
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=2
Environment=DAEMON_CONF=/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/default/hostapd
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/hostapd -B -P /run/hostapd.pid -B $DAEMON_OPTS ${DAEMON_CONF}

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem. By mistake, you set the config file `/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf` to **DAEMON_OPTS** instead of **DAEMON_CONF**.

**1.** Add `DAEMON_CONF="/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf"` to `/etc/default/hostapd`.

**2.** Comment `DAEMON_OPTS= ...` or remove all the line.

**3.** `service hostapd restart`.

---

Another possibility is about "Wifi Country Code". Run `raspi-config` and go to `4 Localisation Options` then `I4 Change Wi-fi Country`. Finally, set your country. I set `IR Iran` and it has worked.

---

If you are pi 4 and get the `Could not communicate with wpa_supplicant` after changing Wifi country, follow [this link](https://www.qlcplus.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=12468#p54247).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104848/discussion-on-answer-by-m-rostami-hostapd-problems-while-setting-up-pi-4-as-acc).