# Problem with wifi access point

Tags: pi-3b+, access-point

I have a problem with wifi access point on Raspberry 3B+.

/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf:

```
interface=wlan0
driver=nl80211
ssid=Rpi_ap
hw_mode=g
channel=7
ieee80211n=1
wmm_enabled=0
macaddr_acl=0
auth_algs=1
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
wpa=2
wpa_passphrase=1234567890
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
logger_syslog=-1
ht_capab=[HT40][SHORT-GI-20][DSSS_CCK-40]
```

/etc/dnsmasq.conf

```
interface=wlan0
dhcp-range=192.168.5.100,192.168.5.200,255.255.255.0,24h
```

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ifconfig wlan0

```
wlan0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.5.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.5.255
    inet6 fe80::ba27:ebff:fe5c:49c7  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether b8:27:eb:5c:49:c7  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 19442  bytes 1854583 (1.7 MiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 1101  bytes 146273 (142.8 KiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

i do

```
sudo ifconfig wlan0 192.168.5.1 netmask 255.255.255.0 broadcast 192.168.5.255
sudo systemctl start dnsmasq.service
sudo hostapd -d /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
```

output here https://pastebin.com/EAxFFeA4

As result i have no access point. What i do wrong? What could be the reason?

UPD:

I found a mistake in cat /etc/default/hostapd (thanks @M. Rostami) and fixed it. But acceess point didn't appear.

/etc/default/hostap:

```
DAEMON_CONF="/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf"
```

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo service hostapd status

```
● hostapd.service - Advanced IEEE 802.11 AP and IEEE 802.1X/WPA/WPA2/EAP Authenticator
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/hostapd.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: active (running) since Wed 2020-03-11 14:15:29 MSK; 2min 21s ago
Process: 1309 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/hostapd -B -P /run/hostapd.pid -B $DAEMON_OPTS ${DAEMON_CONF} (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Main PID: 1310 (hostapd)
Tasks: 1 (limit: 2200)
Memory: 1.8M
CGroup: /system.slice/hostapd.service
       └─1310 /usr/sbin/hostapd -B -P /run/hostapd.pid -B 
/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf

мар 11 14:15:29 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Advanced IEEE 802.11 AP and IEEE 802.1X/WPA/WPA2/EAP Authenticator...
мар 11 14:15:29 raspberrypi hostapd[1309]: Configuration file: /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
мар 11 14:15:29 raspberrypi hostapd[1309]: wlan0: Could not connect to kernel driver
мар 11 14:15:29 raspberrypi hostapd[1309]: Using interface wlan0 with hwaddr b8:27:eb:5c:49:c7 and ssid "Rpi_ap"
мар 11 14:15:29 raspberrypi hostapd[1309]: wlan0: interface state UNINITIALIZED->ENABLED
мар 11 14:15:29 raspberrypi hostapd[1309]: wlan0: AP-ENABLED
мар 11 14:15:29 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Advanced IEEE 802.11 AP and IEEE 802.1X/WPA/WPA2/EAP Authenticator.
```

UPD2:

New data.
if I set static ip address for wlan0 in /etc/networks/interfaces and then reboot i have access point after boot. If set static ip address by command "ifconfig wlan0 192.168.5.1 netmask 255.255.255.0 broadcast 192.168.5.255" i have no access point after "sudo systemctl start dnsmasq.service" and "sudo systemctl start hostapd.service".

Comment: Add the output of these commands: `cat /etc/default/hostapd` - `sudo service hostapd status` -- Did you follow [this procedure](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point.md)?

Comment: i did follow this procedure exclude routing

Comment: You may be configured `/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf` in a wrong way. Check/Change the channel. Also, check the `/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf` on [this answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/106018/44221).

Comment: If you that `/etc/default/hostapd` configured well, you don't need to run `sudo hostapd -d /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf`. Just start `hostapd` service by `sudo service hostapd start` / `restart`.

Comment: i have new problem. Read topic update pls.

Comment: As you configure the IP address by `/etc/networks/interfaces`, the OS is obsolete like Jessie, right?

Comment: And if you set IP at boot, it can be a problem with steps. I mean, the `dnsmasq` needs an IP address for the interface that you set there. Therefore, you set the IP address for `wlan0` at boot then `dnsmasq` or other packages will start without any problem. (guess)

Comment: i use "sudo ifconfig wlan0 192.168.5.1 netmask 255.255.255.0 broadcast 192.168.5.255". it is root. is it wrong? how i can change wlan0 ip adress without root?

Comment: Finally i want arbitrarily change access point and wifi client. Now i can switch on and switch off wifi client. But can't switch on and switch off access point

Comment: You use `wlan0` (RPi Wi-Fi card) for your client and your AP ?

Comment: @Ephemeral yes, i use wlan0 for client and ap

Comment: @dzukp, ok, in the same time ? what is your final goal ?

Comment: @Ephemeral no, i switch off client then switch on ap. Now i can't switch on ap. My goal is if rpi can't found wifi it swich on access point.

Comment: @dzukp, ok, if I follow your last UPD2, then you have an access point at boot and you try to reassign an IP addr to the interface and to start hostpad. And then you have no access point , this is right ?

Comment: @Ephemeral yes, you are right

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105441/discussion-between-ephemeral-and-dzukp).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this before running your access point :

```
sudo kill -9 $(pidof hostapd dnsmasq dhclient wpa_supplicant)
```

or before your commands try only

```
echo $(pidof hostapd dnsmasq dhclient wpa_supplicant)
```

for showing any already running process able to interfere.

The `echo` command must return nothing if all is good for starting your AP