# Network authentification for Raspberry 3b+

Tags: networking, pi-3b+, login

I am a beginner with raspberries and I wanted to modify the hotspot of the raspberry. I would like that anyone could enter the hotspot with a password, but in order to really use the functionalities of it, he has to authentificate himself with a login.

I don't know if you can imagine, but the same system is used in bus- or hospital-wifis, for example. You connect to them (there is **no password to connect to the hotspot**), but in order to use the WiFi, you need to login with a **username and password on a website** you got redirected to.

Now I would like to recreate the same system on my Raspberry 3b+. Is this even possible? If so, how? I haven't found anything useful yet.

Another question, but this one is not so important: would there be a possiblity to **scan a QR-code** in order to get to the login page? Would be nice to experiment with this, and if anyone has an answer, I would be glad if you could share it with me!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The technology you are looking for is called a captive portal and sits better under the general Linux exchange than here. A classic solution is based on nodogsplash  found at https://github.com/nodogsplash/nodogsplash As for QR codes they can point to a URL that could be the log-on page many free web generators  e.g. https://www.qr-code-generator.com/   As neither of these are Pi dependant I'm voting for a close.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [raspberry pi as access point with captive portal](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/88438/raspberry-pi-as-access-point-with-captive-portal)

Comment: @Andyroo I asked kinda the same question on stack overflow, but it got moved to this forum. Sorry, don't know where it's okay to ask. But yes, I think the captive portal is what I am looking for! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev I think that's it, thanks!

Comment: You may still want to ask about the QR-code once you get the portal running if you can't figure it out yourself. It's best not to ask several questions in one post on this site, that only invites partial answers.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev Gonna see what I can do, thanks!